# How Verilog or VHDL projects are implement as physical chips?

Tags: hardware, hdl

In real life, how would I implement a circuit design using Verilog and VHDL as physical chip? Do I send the code to some third party so it manufactures the chip, like with PCB printing providers?

Comment: An ASIC is the general term you're looking for, there are quite a few questions / answers here on various aspects of getting them made try `is:question asic` in the search box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, though the details are a lot more involved and it's an expensive process; probably only worth considering if you need a million such chips.

More normally you would buy a "blank chip" called an FPGA, and compile the design for that chip, using the vendor's own (often free) tools. Usually the design is programmed into a second chip (a ROM) and loaded into the FPGA when power is applied, but there are Flash based FPGAs which don't need a separate ROM.

Examples : [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/) or [Altera](http://www.altera.com/) are the two biggest FPGA vendors.

Often you might begin with a [Starter Kit](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/HW-SPAR3A-SK-UNI-G.htm) from one of the FPGA vendors, offering the chip on a demonstration board with a range of switches, LEDs and interfaces to other systems, to make prototyping easier.

The tools include a simulator : it is important to get your design right (or as close as you can) in simulation before trying to get it working in real hardware. They also include a synthesis tool,  which translates the VHDL design into the specific gates, memories etc available on the chip, and "Place&Route" tools to arrange and connect those gates in a valid arrangement for that chip, and analysis tools to verify the design is fast enough for your purpose.